# Run a loop for each semicolon

Tags: php, mysql, loops

In my MySQL table I have a column with name "datei". For now each field contains a path - e.g. fileadmin/media/pdf/AGB.pdf

This is how my PHP looks like:

```
$Inhalt .= '<div class="DLB_Download_Zeile">
    <a href="'.$Downloads->datei.'" target="_blank">
        <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Bild"><img src="fileadmin/media/images/pdficon.png" width="30" alt="PDF Icon"></div>
        <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Link">'.$Downloads->dateiname.'</div>
    </a>
</div>';
```

I would now like to set the databse field to: `fileadmin/media/pdf/AGB.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherPDF.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherFile.pdf`

That mean in PHP I would need to run a loop that generates the same HTML for each path separated by the semicolon. How can I do this?

Comment: use `explode();` with `';'` and loop threw the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to do using this:

```
$string = 'fileadmin/media/pdf/AGB.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherPDF.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherFile.pdf';
$paths = explode(';', $string);
foreach ($paths as $path) {
    //Your code here
}
```

The `explode()` will split the sting at the semicolon's.
This can also be reversed to get a string again to put it in the database.

```
$string = implode(';', $paths);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$value = 'fileadmin/media/pdf/AGB.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherPDF.pdf;fileadmin/media/pdf/anotherFile.pdf';

$array = explode(';', $value);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me!